# cordova emulate not loading app into endroid amulator

Tags: cordova, android-emulator, visual-studio-cordova

i am using visual studio 2015 update 3 on windows 10 64bit pro , 
here is my java info

Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
java version "1.7.0_55"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode, sharing)

and my cordova version is **Cordova version: 6.2.0**

availabe android target

### Available Android targets:

id: 1 or "android-23"
     Name: Android 6.0
     Type: Platform
     API level: 23
     Revision: 1
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : no ABIs.

in visual studio and in command prompt , emulator runs but without app , 
i have gone all the way and set up ANDROID_HOME environment variable and added ANDROID_HOME/tools, and ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools to my PATH.

but it  is not working .

any possible suggestion ?
sometimes solving issues is really painful.

when i run emulator indepemdently and then i use cordova emulate android , the app loads into emulator

Comment: yes build is successful

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, wrong answer. Since your Android is running level 23, it needs Java 1.8. You need to download J8 yourself and link VS to it using Tools->Options->Tools for Apache Cordova->Environmental Variable Overrides